# How do you avoid plotting NA values in layer_lines using the ggvis-library?

Tags: r, plot, ggvis

The following code will produce a simple graph, but at x=5 the y variable will appear to be at the top of the plot. At x=3 the z-variable appears to be at top. Is there any option to avoid this?

[image]

I am plotting several lines from the same dataframe, so I cannot just omit the row. However, that is effectively what I want to do for this layer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
x = 1:10
y = x
y[5] <- NA
z = -x
z[3] <- NA
dat <- data.frame(x,y,z)
dat %>% ggvis(~x,~y) %>% layer_lines() %>% layer_lines(~x,~z)
```

Comment: What is would your desired graphic look like?  Are you hoping for a gap in the line when you have a missing value?

Comment: Gap would be preferred. But I think many solutions would be more "natural" than this behaviour.

Comment: There is an open issue on the github repository referring to [this google groups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggvis/T1sGhQA3B9o).  A couple options given as answers to that question might help you.